# Array modifier - duplicate around a circle produces strange results

Tags: modifiers, 3d-cursor

According to various sources on the interwebs, the process for duplicating an object around a circle is thus:

- Move the 3D cursor to the centre of rotation
- Create an empty at that point
- Move the origin of the object you want to duplicate to the position of the cursor
- Select the object you wish to duplicate around the circle.
- Create an array modifier with fixed count and an object offset set to the empty, deselecting relative and constant offset
- Rotate the empty and see the duplicates of your object rotate around the array.

When I attempt to do this, the following happens:
I get copies of the object distorted and arrayed along some other path - maybe rotated, but I don't understand why the distortion is happening and the array is not rotated around the z axis of the empty.

See the screenshot below - the blue arrow is pointing to the original object. I've also attached the system-info.txt dump below.

The modifier settings are in the bottom right of the second screenshot. What I'm expecting to see is something like this youtube clip in the top screenshot.  What I'm getting is the second screenshot below.  Why is this happening?

Update.  The cylinder has had some transforms done to it before the array is applied.  If I do it with an untransformed object, The technique works as described.  How do I apply this to the transformed object without re-applying the original transformations?

Further update: Here's the file showing the strange transformations happening.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
=====================================
= Blender 2.91.0 System Information =
=====================================


Blender:
=====================================

version: 2.91.0, branch: master, commit date: 2020-11-25 08:34, hash: 0f45cab862b8, type: Release
build date: 2020-11-25, 09:02:56
platform: Windows
binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\blender.exe'
build cflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /nologo /J /Gd /MP /bigobj -openmp     
build cxxflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /EHsc /nologo /J /Gd /MP /EHsc /bigobj /permissive- /Zc:twoPhase- -openmp /std:c++17 /Zc:__cplusplus     
build linkflags: /MACHINE:X64  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:2097152 /ignore:4049 /ignore:4217 /ignore:4221
build system: CMake

Python:
=====================================

version: 3.7.7 (default, Jun 13 2020, 11:11:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogatepass
paths:
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\startup'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\python37.zip'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\python\\DLLs'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\python\\lib'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\python'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\python\\lib\\site-packages'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\freestyle\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\addons'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\addons_contrib'

Python (External Binary):
=====================================

binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\python\\bin\\python.EXE'
version: Python 3.7.7

Directories:
=====================================

scripts:
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.91\\2.91\\scripts'
user scripts: 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts'
pref scripts: None
datafiles: 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\datafiles'
config: 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\config'
scripts : 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\scripts'
autosave: 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.91\\autosave'
tempdir: 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\blender_a09876\\'

FFmpeg:
=====================================

avcodec:   '58, 54, 100'
avdevice:  '58,  8, 100'
avformat:  '58, 29, 100'
avutil:    '56, 31, 100'
swscale:   ' 5,  5, 100'

SDL:
=====================================

Version: 2.0.12
Loading method: linked (WITH_SDL_DYNLOAD=OFF)

Other Libraries:
=====================================

OpenColorIO:  1,  1,  1
OpenImageIO:  2,  1, 15
OpenShadingLanguage:  1, 10, 10
OpenSubdiv:  0,  0,  0
OpenVDB:  7,  0,  0
Alembic:  1,  7, 12
USD:  0, 20,  5

OpenGL:
=====================================

renderer:   'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'
vendor:     'Intel'
version:    '4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.5161'
extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays
    GL_ARB_base_instance
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_compatibility
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer
    GL_ARB_debug_output
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp
    GL_ARB_depth_texture
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions
    GL_ARB_fragment_program
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_multisample
    GL_ARB_multitexture
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_point_parameters
    GL_ARB_point_sprite
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
    GL_ARB_robustness
    GL_ARB_sample_shading
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
    GL_ARB_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_precision
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing
    GL_ARB_shadow
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing
    GL_ARB_sync
    GL_ARB_tessellation_shader
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_texture_compression
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
    GL_ARB_texture_float
    GL_ARB_texture_gather
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
    GL_ARB_texture_rg
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
    GL_ARB_timer_query
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_program
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
    GL_ARB_viewport_array
    GL_ARB_window_pos
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil
    GL_EXT_abgr
    GL_EXT_bgra
    GL_EXT_blend_color
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract
    GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements
    GL_EXT_fog_coord
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_EXT_packed_float
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal
    GL_EXT_secondary_color
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
    GL_EXT_texture3D
    GL_EXT_texture_array
    GL_EXT_texture_buffer
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_EXT_texture_integer
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm
    GL_EXT_texture_storage
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_INTEL_map_texture
    GL_INTEL_performance_queries
    GL_INTEL_performance_query
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_KHR_debug
    GL_NV_blend_square
    GL_NV_conditional_render
    GL_NV_primitive_restart
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays
    GL_WIN_swap_hint
    WGL_ARB_buffer_region
    WGL_ARB_create_context
    WGL_ARB_create_context_profile
    WGL_ARB_create_context_robustness
    WGL_ARB_extensions_string
    WGL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
    WGL_ARB_make_current_read
    WGL_ARB_multisample
    WGL_ARB_pbuffer
    WGL_ARB_pixel_format
    WGL_ARB_pixel_format_float
    WGL_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
    WGL_EXT_create_context_es_profile
    WGL_EXT_depth_float
    WGL_EXT_extensions_string
    WGL_EXT_pixel_format_packed_float
    WGL_EXT_swap_control
    WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear
    WGL_NV_DX_interop

Implementation Dependent OpenGL Limits:
=====================================

Maximum DrawElements Vertices:  1048576
Maximum DrawElements Indices:   1048576

GLSL:
Maximum Varying Floats: 64
Maximum Vertex Attributes:  16
Maximum Vertex Uniform Components:  4096
Maximum Fragment Uniform Components:    4096
Maximum Vertex Image Units: 16
Maximum Fragment Image Units:   16
Maximum Pipeline Image Units:   96

Cycles:
=====================================


CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX

OpenCL device capabilities:
Number of platforms: 1
Platform #0
    Platform Name: Intel(R) OpenCL
    Platform Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
    Platform Version: OpenCL 1.2 
    Platform Profile: FULL_PROFILE
    Platform Extensions: cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_d3d11_sharing cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics
    Number of devices: 2
        Device: #0
            Device Name:        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz
            Device Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
            Device OpenCL C Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
            Device Profile: FULL_PROFILE
            Device Version: OpenCL 1.2 (Build 76427)
            Device Extensions: cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_intel_printf cl_ext_device_fission cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing 
            Device Max clock frequency (MHz): 2600
            Device Max compute units: 4
            Device Max work group size: 1024
        Device: #1
            Device Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
            Device Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
            Device OpenCL C Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
            Device Profile: FULL_PROFILE
            Device Version: OpenCL 1.2 
            Device Extensions: cl_intel_d3d11_nv12_media_sharing cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_gl_depth_images cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_gl_msaa_sharing cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_motion_estimation 
            Device Max clock frequency (MHz): 1200
            Device Max compute units: 16
            Device Max work group size: 512

Enabled add-ons:
=====================================

io_anim_bvh (version: (1, 0, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py)
io_curve_svg (version: (), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_curve_svg\__init__.py)
io_mesh_ply (version: (), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_mesh_ply\__init__.py)
io_mesh_stl (version: (1, 1, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py)
io_mesh_uv_layout (version: (1, 1, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_mesh_uv_layout\__init__.py)
io_scene_fbx (version: (4, 21, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py)
io_scene_gltf2 (version: (1, 4, 40), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py)
io_scene_obj (version: (3, 8, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py)
io_scene_x3d (version: (2, 2, 5), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\__init__.py)
cycles (version: (), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\cycles\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Hello. System information is most likely not needed. You can upload your blend file instead (not obvious to see how the selected object is). Please use this site to do it and copy the obtained link here. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: maybe you have transformed your empty? Apply its transformation with Ctrl A and rotate again to see what's happenning, or maybe share your file as suggested by Lemon

Comment: @lemon - I've uploaded the file as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object scales are totally uneven. In *"object offset"* mode when the modifier is calculated, it takes into account both the transforms of the object and the transforms of the array modifier pivot (the empty here).

So simply apply scales on the cylinder <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then choose "scale".

Though, if you want to keep the object transforms, you can select the cylinder, shift select the empty and use the operator *"align selected scale to active"* (search for it in the search panel). This operator copies the cylinder scale to the empty. As they now have the same scale, that compensate the difference.

Comment: It turns out that's what worked.  Once you apply the transformations it stops trying to apply them on every iteration.